# Python spynner not loading my page

Tags: python, spynner

I install python spynner im tring to load my page "http://nexo.rf.gd/app.js" 
Cant load this please help
I try with mechinize.Browser() but it can't load html
Then i try with selenium remote webdrivers and finally i try with spynner because this browser can able to run js but dont know how ?? Help me please

## with mechanize.Browser() ##

```
import mechanize
Br = mechanize.Browser()
Br.open('http://nexo.rf.gd/app.js')
Br.response().read()
```

Answer is HTML code witch says this site need js enable browser

### answer will be 'import sqlite'`

Comment: Hi Harry, welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Questions on this website are to be very specific. Please rewrite your question to include the code you're having an issue with, things that you've tried that haven't worked, and/or other resources you're using and don't understand, along with a clarification of what _exactly_ your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a way to open my page html code #witch is import sqlite3

Every browser fails but with **dryscrape** my problem solve thanks anyway